# fill in missing data gaps in a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I'm looking to fill in some missing data gaps caused by missing reporting_month date. I would like to fill the data gaps with the previous recorded values.

Below is the Sample I have with the 2,3,4 & 6 months missing.

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
    (reporting_year datetime,
     repoting_month integer,
     Value integer) 

    INSERT  INTO @test
    VALUES  
    ('2022',    1,  3),
    ('2022',    5,  4),
    ('2022',    7,  4),
    ('2022',    8,  5),
    ('2022',    9,  5),
    ('2022',    10, 5);
```

Below are the expected values with the additional rows populated from the previous records.

```
DECLARE @required TABLE
    (reporting_year datetime,
     repoting_month integer,
     Value integer) 

    INSERT  INTO @required
    VALUES  
    ('2022',    1,  3),
    ('2022',    2,  3),
    ('2022',    3,  3),
    ('2022',    4,  3),
    ('2022',    5,  4),
    ('2022',    6,  4),
    ('2022',    7,  4),
    ('2022',    8,  5),
    ('2022',    9,  5),
    ('2022',    10, 5);
```

Comment: just FYI, treating `reporting_year` as a `datetime` will interpret all those year values as `2022-01-01 00:00:00:000`

Comment: It's a bit unclear as to whether you want to `insert` new rows into `@test` that look like, but don't represent, actual values or to create a `select` query, or perhaps a `view`, that will return a value for each year/month pair over the appropriate range of dates, e.g for use in a report. Perhaps you could clarify?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GENERATE_SERIES` to generate more rows for each one that has missing rows following it.

You can find the next row's value using `LEAD`.

```sql
WITH nextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      LEAD(repoting_month) OVER (PARTITION BY reporting_year ORDER BY repoting_month) AS nextMonth
    FROM @test t
)
SELECT
  t.reporting_year,
  t.repoting_month + ISNULL(g.value, 0),
  t.Value
FROM nextValues t
OUTER APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, t.nextMonth - t.repoting_month - 1) g;
```

In older versions of SQL Server, you need a [numbers generator](https://sqlperformance.com/2021/01/t-sql-queries/number-series-solutions-1).

```sql
WITH nextValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      LEAD(repoting_month) OVER (PARTITION BY reporting_year ORDER BY repoting_month) AS nextMonth
    FROM @test t
)
SELECT
  t.reporting_year,
  t.repoting_month + ISNULL(g.value, 0),
  t.Value
FROM nextValues t
OUTER APPLY dbo.GetNums(0, ISNULL(t.nextMonth - t.repoting_month - 1, 0)) g;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/IhcdKBAt)

Answer (score 2):

Rationale -

Note I changed the original data type of reporting_year to integer. Datetime seems like it was probably a typo. Doesn't make too much difference either way. If it truly is datetime just extract the year.

Get all months in a year. You can hardcode instead if you want for simplicity.

Get all possible year and month combinations. Left joining this to your original data will get you Nulls for your missing months. This is also written to cover all years in the data, in case your real data has more than 2022.

max(abc) over (order by xyz rows between ...) is a nifty trick that will get you the last distinct value of abc ordering by xyz. If you coalesce to this derived value it will fill in the last non-null value by month.

The last EXIST is probably heavy handed and you could push that filter up, but it's just there to get rid of November and December since the upper bound of your data is October.

Fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/0CnNt6K1

```
create table test
    (reporting_year integer,
     reporting_month integer,
     Value integer) 

    INSERT  INTO test
    VALUES  
    (2022,    1,  3),
    (2022,    5,  4),
    (2022,    7,  4),
    (2022,    8,  5),
    (2022,    9,  5),
    (2022,    10, 5);

WITH 
possible_months AS (
    SELECT 1 AS p_month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT p_month+1 from possible_months WHERE p_month+1<=12
),
all_years as (
    select distinct
           reporting_year
      from test
),
all_year_months as (
select ay.reporting_year,
       pm.p_month
  from all_years ay
 cross
  join possible_months pm
)
select aym.reporting_year,
       aym.p_month,
       coalesce(
           t.value,
           max(t.value) over(
             order by aym.reporting_year,
                      aym.p_month
               rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
           ))  as imputed_value
  from all_year_months aym
  left
  join test t
    on aym.reporting_year = t.reporting_year
   and aym.p_month = t.reporting_month
 where exists
         (
           select 1
             from test t2
            where aym.p_month <= t2.reporting_month
              and aym.reporting_year = t2.reporting_year
         );
```

| reporting_year | p_month | imputed_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 3 |
| 2022 | 2 | 3 |
| 2022 | 3 | 3 |
| 2022 | 4 | 3 |
| 2022 | 5 | 4 |
| 2022 | 6 | 4 |
| 2022 | 7 | 4 |
| 2022 | 8 | 5 |
| 2022 | 9 | 5 |
| 2022 | 10 | 5 |