# LAG Function Impala

Tags: sql, function, impala

I have a table that looks like this.

```
exchange_rate_date  from_currency   to_currency
12/18/23            CAD             USD
12/17/23            NULL            NULL
12/16/23            NULL            NULL
12/15/23            CAD             USD
```

[TEST DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liSNB.png)

I need to fill the NULL using the values below for From_Currency and for column To_Currency.  I've tried using LAG function

```
LAG(a.from_currency,1) OVER(PARTITION BY a.from_currency,a.to_currency ORDER BY a.from_currency DESC)
```

and I'm still getting NULLS.  What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I would recommend adding a couple more rows in your sample data, showing that you're not always converting from and to the same currency. Also, no need for images since you have nicely formatted text. Also add another formatted text area with your desired output.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56992735/find-next-lowest-value-over-partition . It looks like impala supports RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING . I don't have impala or and it's not a fiddle option so can't check for sure. So in yours, depending on what Impala supports, you'd either leave out the PARTITION BY or do a PARTITION BY 1 if the clause is required.

Comment: For a closer analogue, you can check out my answer to this question just today https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77692604/fill-in-missing-data-gaps-in-a-table/77692812#77692812 . Where the similar bit is finding the last non-null value with the coalesce.

Comment: What you really need is a `LAG(...) IGNORE NULLS OVER(...)` function, but it appears that Impala does not support that. My other normal go-to (for other DBMSs) is a `CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ...)` to find the preceding non-null value, but it seems that Impala does not support that syntax either. Perhaps someone else here knows if there is an **Impala equivalent to CROSS APPLY**.

Comment: Don't believe there currently is a cross join equivalent (i.e. no lateral joins) and as far as I know it won't even allow correlated subqueries in a select clause. Is Impala the only option available e.g. could you use Python? **btw** is this just a display need or are you attempting to update the data itself?